# IP packet and MAC Destination Address

Tags: tcp, ip, data-link-layer

I've a simple question about IP and MAC.
Lets say we have two LANs, A and B, connected by a Bridge (no Network Layer). We have host 'X', which sends an IP packet to host 'Y'. It will send it through a MAC frame. The Payload of that MAC Frame will be our ip packet.

The question is: since X doesn't know Y's MAC Address, which MAC Destination Address will be used in the Frame's Header?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Not a programming question but your question is moot. You can't address host 'Y' if you don't have an address for it, MAC, IP or otherwise. You could fire the packet as a broadcast and hope that host 'Y' understands that the packet is for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `X` doesn't know the MAC address of `Y` it will first send an ARP request to `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff` (broadcast) requesting the MAC address for the IP address of `Y`. `Y` will respond with it's MAC address which `X` will then use as a destination MAC address to send the frame.

Btw, since the bridge is in between they're actually on the same LAN, not A and B.

Comment: Isn't the MAC Destination Address supposed to be the next hop? In a general case (host linked to a Router, which wants to send and ip packet to a remote host), shouldn't the router interface mac address be the MAC Destination Address?

Comment: You are correct, the MAC destination address of the frame is the MAC of the next hop. But in this case the next hop is `Y` since bridges, switches, hubs etc. are not considered to be hops.